# Probability of a fair coin

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Say that we throw a fair coin $n$ times. We say that the sequence is $i$-good if the value of $i$, $i+1$, $i+2$ are all head.

For example, in the scenario $THHHHTHHH$, the second, third, and seventh digits are good. Let $X$ be the number of $i$ good indices. Compute the expectation of $X$.

Comment: Welcome to SE! Could you show us a bit about what you've tried?

Comment: You quoted the exercise you are supposed to solve. Now what is your question about it?

Comment: Linearity of expectation!

Comment: Im having trouble understanding the problem and was hoping an answer would allow me to figure out the rest of my exercises

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: However the terms are not independent: If the sequence is $1$-good, the probability that it is also $2$-good is $1/2$. If it is not $1$-good, the probability that is is $2$-good is only $1/14$

Comment: Linearity of Expectation does not care about Independence or dependencies.

Comment: @celtschk Graham points out the brilliant thing about linearity of expectation!

Answer (score 1):

As Lord Shark the Unknown commented, this is a job for the Linearity of Expectation!  With a side order of Indicator Random Variables.

Let $X_i$ equal $1$ if the string is $i$-good, and equal $0$ otherwise.   The expectation of such a Bernoulli random variable equals the probability that it is $1$.$$\mathsf E(X_i)=\mathsf P(X_i=1)$$

Evaluate these values.

Now the count of $i$-good indices, $~X~$ , equals the sum of the first $n-2$ indicator random variables (since the last two are certainly zero). $$X=~\sum_{i=1}^{n-2} X_i$$

Put this together with the rule of Linearity of Expectation and find the expectation, $\mathsf E(X)$.

Comment: thxs! im still having trouble understanding but ill keep trying!